# Could not start Selenium session: in Junit 3.8.2 test and selenium 3.4 on linux

Tags: java, selenium, junit3

My environment:

linux ubuntu

selenium-html-runner-3.4.0.jar

selenium-java-3.4.0

selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar

to build I do:

```
 javac -cp "/usr/share/java/junit.jar:/home/me/ushare/hobo/selenium/selenium-html-runner-3.4.0.jar:." TestHobo2.java
```

to run selenium-server:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar
```

to run the test I do:

```
java junit.textui.TestRunner TestHobo2
```

and I get:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not start Selenium session:
>
> at
>   com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.start(DefaultSelenium.java:114)
>   at
>   com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestBase.setUp(SeleneseTestBase.java:139)
>   at
>   com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestBase.setUp(SeleneseTestBase.java:108)
>   at
>   com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestCase.setUp(SeleneseTestCase.java:113)
>   at TestHobo2.setUp(TestHobo2.java:10)    at
>   com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestCase.runBare(SeleneseTestCase.java:289)
>   Caused by: com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException:
>
> at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError(HttpCommandProcessor.java:111)
>     at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.doCommand(HttpCommandProcessor.java:105)
>     at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.getString(HttpCommandProcessor.java:277)
>     at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.start(HttpCommandProcessor.java:239)
>     at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.start(DefaultSelenium.java:105)
>           ... 15 more

Here is my test case:

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestHobo2 extends SeleneseTestCase {
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        setUp("http://www.example.com/", "*chrome");
    }
    public void testGetLink() throws Exception {
        selenium.type("name=p_loc", "groove");
        selenium.click("css=input[type=\"Submit\"]");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    }
}
```

Edit 2017/07/20 More info:

I am using Firefox version 52.0.2 (64-bit).

Should I be getting the following after the build?

`Note: TestHobod2.java uses or overrides a deprecated API. 
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.`

`geckodriver -v`

1500554646753 geckodriver INFO geckodriver 0.18.0

1500554646753 webdriver::httpapi DEBUG Creating routes

1500554646764 geckodriver ERROR Address in use (os error 98)

Comment: Have you tried creating `RemoteDriver` by hand?

Comment: No. Can you provide an example? I got this test code from exporting Selenium IDE test.

Comment: http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp You can use `RemoteDriver` insteed of eg.`FirefoxDriver` with proper settings ofc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you have properly defined on which ip address and port is selenium running? Run your selenium server and put http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/ link into your browser. Try to create new session manually (click on create session and select browser, see image below), new browser blank window should appear. If this is working correctly than selenium server is ok. Then there can be problem with connection between server and your runner. 

[screen of selenium hub with create session option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoGco.png)

Do you have correctly setup selenium driver? For example I'm using

```
new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/"),DesiredCapabilities.firefox())
```

EDIT1: Show example of setUp method which create instance of RemoteDriver, create new browser session and fill url.

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://192.168.4.52:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
driver.manage().window().maximize()//maximaze window as possible
driver.get("www.google.com"); //navigate to google, i.e. fill url into opened session
```

Comment: Wow. This is a lot more promising... the new firefox window did open up. Where do I put the `new RemoteWeb` code line - setUp() or the test() ? Thanks a lot in advance. BTW can you explain the pont of setUp() within the setUp()?

Comment: Edit: I'm struggling with formatting of comment, so I will update my origin answer.

Comment: Now everything clicked into place. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the codebase, and trying to map your shared test code, seems to suggest that you will end up invoking a Firefox browser. The underlying implementation in Selenium has ensured that this will cause your test code to resort to perhaps using firefox.

Can you please ensure that you have made [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver) downloaded and made available in your PATH variable ?

If that doesn't fix the problem (which could mostly be due to mismatch between the firefox version that you have in your desktop and the geckodriver version ), you can try switching to using `Google Chrome`.

You can switch to google chrome by

**Changing** : `setUp("http://www.example.com/", "*chrome");`
**To** : `setUp("http://www.example.com/", "*googlechrome");`

And see if that spins off the browser (For google chrome you would need to ensure you have [chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) downloaded and made available in your local machine)

Comment: The same failure with both drivers. I am using Firefox version 52.0.2 (64-bit). Should I be getting the following? Note: TestHobod2.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
geckodriver -v
1500554646753   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.18.0
1500554646753   webdriver::httpapi  DEBUG   Creating routes
1500554646764   geckodriver ERROR   Address in use (os error 98)

Comment: The message related `overrides a deprecated API` is unrelated to the problem. Have you ensured that `chromedriver` is part of your PATH ? Where is located ? When you run `echo %PATH%` from a command prompt do you see the `chromedriver` location in the console ? Also I noticed that your error says `ERROR address in use`. Can you please ensure that all geckodriver instances that could be running are killed via `taskmanager` or `kill` command ?

Comment: That error was in response to `geckodriver -v` command. There were no other instances of that driver. I could not get the shown test to work as is. However, the modifications recommended by @Martin got me to the working version of the test. That is why I accepted his answer.